# File reading in C++ error in big files

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am writing an algorithm in C++ which will read a file with numbers with a specific format and then each  ( number minus 1 ) that is being read will be the position in an array called `Amount` and it will be inicreased by 1. The file format is like so

> 10 5 
>      1 2 3 4 1 5 1 5 2 1

All the values are separated with a space. The first 2 on the first line are the variables N and M and the values from the second line are the ones that will set the position in the array that will be increased. The part of the algorithm for this is :

```
    int N,M,i;

    FILE *read = fopen("data.in", "r");
    fscanf(read, "%d %d ", &N, &M);
    int Amount[M];
    fill_n(Amount,M, 0); 

    for( i =0; i < N; i++)
    {
        fscanf(read, "%d ", &K);
        Amount[K-1]++;
    }
```

This algorithm has no problem with a small amount of numbers but I need it to work with up to 1 million numbers, in which case it crashes. What should I change?

Comment: `int Amount[M]` — you should allocate memory with `new` operator (or `malloc` function in C).

Comment: `int Amount[M];` should not compile.

Comment: The array is probably too big for the stack then. Allocate it dynamically. Also,  in C++ you should work with iostreams in stead of the C library.

Comment: If you want a dynamic array, or an array you set the size of at run-time, then use [std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Also, if you're programming C++, why are you using the old C standar file I/O? Why not use the [C++ standard I/O](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io)?

Comment: @Satus Some compilers have variable-length arrays as an extension.

Comment: this is what the site says itself : "stackoverflow" :D

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, they do, but all compiler I worked with at least gave warnings in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program crashes because the integer array `Amount` cannot be allocated enough memory when M goes to a million numbers.

Allocation of memory to local variable amount is from the stack section, which is limited (around 1 MB). That means M could only take values less than 250000.

So, a better approach would be to allocate memory from the heap section by using new[].

```
int *Amount = new int[M];
```

Don't forget to de-allocate/return the memory allocated from the heap using `delete[]` after the usage of amount before exiting the program.

```
delete[] Amount;
```

So, after incorporating the mentioned changes, the above code would look as follows:

```
int N,M,i;
FILE *read = fopen("data.in", "r");
fscanf(read, "%d %d ", &N, &M);
int *Amount = new int[M];
fill_n(Amount,M, 0);  

for(i =0; i < N; i++) {
    fscanf(read, "%d ", &K);
    Amount[K-1]++;
}

//some logic

delete[] Amount;
```